# Modifying variable value from method

Tags: java

was wondering where im going wrong, any ideas?

Modifying variable value from method

Implement a method empty() in the TicketMachine class that simulates the effect of removing all money from the machine
It should have a void return type and the body should simply set the total variable/field to zero.

Does this method need any parameters? No

Is this method a mutator or accessor? mutator

Paste the whole method into the space below

```
public void empty(int return) 
{ 
balance = 0; 
}
```

Mark: 0 out of 3

Comments:

```
* Test 1 (0.0 out of 3)



TicketMachine.java:26: <identifier> expected
  public void empty(int return)
                        ^
  TicketMachine.java:60: ')' expected
  }
  ^
  2 errors
```

The output should have been:

```
      No it doesn't need parameters 
       and it is a mutator
      TicketMachine emptied successfully
```

This is what was actually produced:

```
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TicketMachine
```

Answer (score 1):

You called your method parameter **return**:

```
public void empty(int return)
```

which is a reserved keyword in Java hence the error above.  Rename the parameter...

Comment: OP mentions that the method shouldn't have parameters. They are putting things between the () and apparently doesn't understand that those are parameters in Java.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.  What or who is OP?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to indicate that there should be no parameters.

> public void empty() {
>           balance = 0;
>    }

Comment: ive try'd that before, in return i got

TicketMachine.java:28: cannot find symbol
symbol : variable balance
location: class TicketMachine
balance = 0;
^

Comment: Is there anymore code? The sample that you have supplied does not have enough detail to be able to fully answer your question. I assumes that there was a variable in the TicketMachine class because it was referred to in your sample code.

Comment: ive added the full programs code, hopefully it could make it easier

Comment: The variable definitions have been commented out. You need to move add a `/` afer the final * in the top comment . As it exists this code will not even compile.

Comment: i did that because iwas playing around with the code, but evene without it being hidden this error still pops up and im still confused

Comment: I have just copied the code, edited the comment added a main method and was able to run the empty method as written withour error. Can you edit your full code post to show the changes that you made.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're actually asking.  But one of the problems might be that `return` in Java is a reserved word.  I can't imagine this ever compiled as you have it.  Change it to something else (`return0` maybe?) and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: TicketMachine.java.28: cannot find symbol\
symbol : variable balance
location: class TicketMachine
balance = 0;
^

i get that error